# Why does the JVM return exit status code 143?

Tags: java, exit-code

A Java application running as an scheduled task on Windows 2003 crashed with no logs or anything that would help to find out what happened. The only information available, is that the application returned code 143 (8F). That error code was retrieved from the scheduled tasks log.

Does anyone knows what that error code (143) stands for? Is it possible that an user logging off could cause the application to be terminated?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JVM error code 143 means [Internal field must be valid](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/cldc-opt-impl/cldc-hi/doc/porting/html/appendix1.html). This is discussed on the [OTN discussion forums](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1522498&tstart=270). However, the conclusion seems to be something killed your process.

I suspect this could indeed be caused by a user logging off.

Comment: That reference you pointed at is for Java ME.  I don't think it is relevant to the OP's problem which is (surely) about a Java SE application.

Comment: Yeah, in fact the reference is pointless. However, I believe it was a process killing the Java application (probably a log off). I could not replicate the issue however.

Comment: Actually, after some time we found it was an antivirus.

Answer (score 13):

143 often means that the application was terminated due to a SIGTERM command. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10231/when-does-the-system-send-a-sigterm-to-a-process

However, please note that an application might use 143 for its own custom result.

Answer (score 3):

An user logging off would signal the `CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT` signal to all running processes. From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376876(v=vs.85).aspx:

> The system also sends the CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT control signal to every
>   process during a log-off operation.

Now, under certain circumstances it will terminate the Java application with error code `143` (`SIGTERM`). See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6871190.

Well, anyway, what you need to stop this from happening is to start Java with the `-Xrs` option. From https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.win.80.doc/diag/appendixes/cmdline/Xrs.html:

> Setting -Xrs prevents the Java™ run time environment from handling any
>   internally or externally generated signals such as SIGSEGV and
>   SIGABRT.

So you should start your Java application with something like:

```
>java -Xrs -jar myapplication.jar
```

PS:

The relation between `SIGTERM` and `143` number is explained in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10231/when-does-the-system-send-a-sigterm-to-a-process#comment13523_10231.