# Successful Hadoop job with errors

Tags: hadoop

I have set up my first simple Hadoop multi-node cluster(I am a newbie) consisting of two nodes, a master-node(also acting as slave-node) and a dedicated slave-node.
I am running a Hadoop "word count" example job, which finishes successfully. Although when i look in the logs i can see an error, this is from TaskTracker log on slave-node:

```
    2013-04-12 00:30:16,436 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Failed validating JVM  
    java.io.IOException: JvmValidate Failed. Ignoring request from task:
    attempt_201304112309_0006_m_000003_0, with JvmId: jvm_201304112309_0006_m_1485441759
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.validateJVM(TaskTracker.java:3434)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.statusUpdate(TaskTracker.java:3504)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:578)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387)

    2013-04-12 00:30:16,515 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DefaultTaskController: Exit code from task is : 143
    2013-04-12 00:30:16,515 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DefaultTaskController: Output from DefaultTaskController's launchTask follows:
    2013-04-12 00:30:16,515 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskController: 
    2013-04-12 00:30:16,516 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM : jvm_201304112309_0006_m_1485441759 exited with exit code 143. Number of tasks it ran: 1
```

Do anyone know what happens here?
Sorry about the ugly code indentation, i couldn´t figure out how to do it properly, this is my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something killed your process, but you mentioned that it finished so Hadoops resilient features kicked in and either ran it on another node or retried it on the same getting your word count done either way. check out the answer to [JVM error code 143](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963811/jvm-returns-error-143)