# When I run this code it return that "exit status 143" in java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, cube, divide-and-conquer

When I run this code it return that "exit status 143" in java, I don't know what's going wrong there, hope someone can help me fix this problem.

```
class Main {
    static double diff(double y, double x, double d){
     if((y*y*y)+d>x)
     return ((y*y*y)+d-x);
     else return(x-(y*y*y)+d);
    }

    static double cubicRoot(double x, double d){
      double start=0 , end=x;
      double e = 0.01;
      while(true){
        double y=(start+end)/2;
        double error = diff(x,y,d);
        if (error <= e)
        return y;
        if(y*y*y+d>x)
        end =y;
        else 
        start =y;
      }
    }

      public static void main(String[] args) {

        double x =10;
        double d =0.1;
        System.out.println("root y is:" + cubicRoot(x,d));

      }
    }
```

Comment: When i start to run program, nothing return on the output screen, and few mins later it return that "exit status 143"

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963811/jvm-returns-error-143

Comment: `static double diff(double y, double x, double d){` - I'm sure you got the order wrong. It should be `static double diff(double x, double y, double d)`.

Comment: Yes you are right sir, could you please tell me why this happened?@JohannesKuhn

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exit code 143 corresponds to SIGTERM, which is the signal sent by default when you run kill .

Did you or the OS kill the process? Is it an infinite loop that you eventually killed?

Comment: Someone fixed it for me it caused because the variable order in the void was wrong. But why it is happened  I mean why I can't write it like "double y, double x, double d"

Comment: Because you are trying to call it like `double error = diff(x,y,d);` and function definition suggest that you have kept the order wrong `    static double diff(double y, double x, double d)`. Naming of variable doesn't really matter but it seems your expected values are in different order